# Are there any restrictions regarding power plugs and wiring in the same wall with plumbing (kitchen adjacent to bathroom)

Tags: electrical, plumbing

I have a kitchen and a bathroom that share a common wall
On one side I have a stove, a dishwasher and two power outlets
On the other side I am going to install a shower and a sink like below

bottom ones from left to right: stove and dishwasher power outlets
top ones: regular above the counter power outlets

**Is this arrangement OK ?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having your large appliances or standard receptacles on the opposite side of a bathroom wall is fine by code. There is nothing special you need to do.
Just a reminder the kitchen requires 2 ea 20 amp small appliance circuits, the bathroom requires it’s own circuit for the receptacles in there.

Comment: they are separated already I did not install these I am just moving the plumbing on that wall